# Sample text in header

Tags: magento-1.9, header, logo

How to add sample text, for example telephone nubmer under the logo in header?
[image]

Comment: Is it magento 1 or 2? Quick option would be adding phone number within the logo image if you don't want to touch template files.

Comment: magento 1.9, 
In the admin panel this function is not present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to edit your template.

Find this file:

```
template/page/html/header.phtml
```

And find your logo html code then place your code below the logo.

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add your text in the header.phtml

goto frontend/your_package/dafault/template/page/html/header.phtml

add your text after logo code.

or

You can create static block, add your text here and call static block in the header.phtml after logo code.

<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```